# c++: I am using template to create an alias declaration and keep getting errors

Tags: c++, templates

I'm not too familiar with template and it's restrictions in C++. I'm creating a generic linked list using template and have a template alias as well. I keep getting error messages for the functions I created using the alias. My current code looks like this:

```cpp
template <typename var>
struct Node
{
    var value;
    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
};

template <typename var>
using nodepointer = Node<var>*;
void addNode(nodepointer &head, nodepointer &tail, var element);
```

The errors I get are:

```
error: variable or field 'addNode' declared void
     void addNode(nodepointer &head, nodepointer &tail, var element);

error: missing template arguments before '&' token
     void addNode(nodepointer &head, nodepointer &tail, var element);
```

Comment: `nodepointer` is still a template.  To use it you need to specify the template parameter

Answer (score 0):

Since `nodepointer` is a template, you need to make `addNode()` be its own template as well (which you need for its `element` parameter anyway) so that you can pass its template parameter to nodepointer's template parameter, eg:

```cpp
template <typename var>
void addNode(nodepointer<var> &head, nodepointer<var> &tail, var element);
```

A single `template` can't be applied to multiple things like you are attempting, unless they are members of a class/struct and the `template` is applied to the entire class/struct as a whole, eg:

```cpp
template <typename var>
struct List
{
    struct Node
    {
        var value;
        Node *next;
        Node *prev;
    };

    using nodepointer = Node*;

    void addNode(var element);

private:
    nodepointer head, tail;
};
```